# Accessing private members within a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, private

Why do we have to copy first then use the getfunction? Why can we just directly use the get function on like `borrowers.getID() == ID` instead of `borrow.getID() == ID`?

I just need an explanation.  I know some things might be missing but I am just very confused here as it looks not very efficient!

```
class ReadershipList {
private:
    ifstream myin;
    ofstream myout;
    string readerfile;
    vector<Borrower> borrowers;
public:
    int findBorrowerbyID(string ID); //Find the borrowers index by ID
    int findBorrowerbyName(string name);
    void addBorrower(Borrower newBorrow); //Add a borrower to the vector of borrowers
    void listBorrowers(); //Prints the list of borrowers
    bool deleteBorrower(string ID); //Delete borrower using ID
    Borrower getBorrowerbyID(string ID); /
    Borrower getBorrowerbyName(string name); //Get borrower details using name
};
```

Why cant I directly access the members?

Instead of using this:

```
bool ReadershipList::deleteBorrower(string ID) {
    Borrower borrow;
    for (int b = 0; b < borrowers.size(); b++) {
        borrow = borrowers[b];
        if (borrow.getID() == ID) {
            borrowers.erase(borrowers.begin() + b);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Because `borrowers` is a `std::vector` and not a `Borrower`?!

Comment: You don't *have to* copy – you can write `borrowers[b].getID()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to copy, you can do

```
bool ReadershipList::deleteBorrower(string ID) {
    for (int b = 0; b < borrowers.size(); b++) {
        if (borrowers[b].getID() == ID) {
            borrowers.erase(borrowers.begin() + b);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

or

```
bool ReadershipList::deleteBorrower(string ID) {
    for (int b = 0; b < borrowers.size(); b++) {
        Borrower & borrow = borrowers[b]; // or better "const Borrower & borrow = borrowers[b];" if "string Borrower::getID() const"

        if (borrow.getID() == ID) {
            borrowers.erase(borrowers.begin() + b);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```